# Can someone please explain how the proof below is wrong for $9=3$?

Tags: fake-proofs

Where is the error?

1. $-27=-27$
2. $81-108=9-36$
3. $9^2 - 2\cdot 9\cdot6 = 3^2 - 2\cdot3\cdot6$
4. $9^2 - 2\cdot9\cdot6 + 6^2 = 3^2 - 2\cdot3\cdot6 + 6^2$
5. $(9-6)^2 = (3-6)^2$
6. $9-6 = 3-6$
7. $9=3$

Comment: $5 \implies 6$ is wrong.

Comment: Step 6: $\sqrt{(3-6)^2}\neq3-6$

Comment: Note that, $$a^2=b^2\implies |a|=|b|$$ not $a=b$

Comment: Typo on line 3: you wrote $2\cdot9\cdot6$ on both sides of the equation but on the right side it should instead be $2\cdot3\cdot6$. This error is repeated on line 4. On line 5 the error disappears, presumably because you copied that line correctly.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: In fake proofs like that you only have to find out where we get the invalid equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^2=b^2$ doesn't imply $a=b$. So the flaw happens while going from 5th to 6th step.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that taking the root gives you two solutions: $$y^2=x\implies y=\pm\sqrt{x}$$So In between $5.$ and $6.$ is where the flaw is made.

Whenever you have fallacies like this try to look at where the math starts to not make sense.